# Magento 2 Child theme of Luma change media query

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

I have a custom theme that is a child of Luma. I see the styles-l min-width is set at 768px. Up until then the styles-m is active. I know if it was in my custom theme I could set that in my default_head_blocks.xml to trigger. But its loading from Luma.

How can I force that to trigger at a higher screen width?

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to set a new width in `default_head_blocks.xml` in your custom theme. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 900px)"/>
    </head>
</page>
```